# Firebase Remote Config - "user in random percentile" with key

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm exploring using Firebase's "User in random percentile" condition to target different segments of a customer-base for A/B testing and have a few questions after reviewing the [Firebase Remote Config Parameters and Conditions documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters#rule_types):

> Each app instance is persistently mapped to a random whole or fractional number, according to a key defined in that project.

1. Assuming that like `setUserProperty` this value persists for all generated percentiles (i.e. those without keys and with keys) [until the app in uninstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817325/firebase-analytics-setuserproperty-persists-through-app-lifecycle). Is this a correct assumption?
2. If a condition maps to a random percentile that is <= 50 and I then change that condition to only target <= 10 (but do not modify the key associated with the random percentile), I expect the 11-50 percentile to now match on the next condition (could be the default) but the original 0 to 10 percentile should still match on the condition. Are the these assumptions correct?
3. Once a random percentile is created for a user, does that value persist across any mutations to conditions so long as the key for that percentile does not change? For example, for key `"firebase_test"` user A's percentile value is 47%. So long as user A does not uninstall the app that user's percentile value will always be 47% for `"firebase_test"`.
4. Is the FirebaseRemoteConfig singleton doing any persistence of values? I'm assuming a fetch after the cache expires will ignore any values returned previously by `getValue` methods and simply return the latest value configured.
5. Is there any way to print out the percentile value a user is assigned for given keys (and no key as well)? For example calling `mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getPercentile("firebase_test")` would return `1.234`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. That's true on iOS. I believe on Android, this value will persist even if you uninstall/reinstall your app.
2. Yes, that assumption is correct. (This is how you can do gradual rollouts of feature with remote config)
3. I believe so, although if you have specific concerns, I'd be happy to hear 'em
4. That's true, assuming you also remember to call `applyFetched` after getting those new values.
5. Nope, there's no way to do this currently.

Comment: Thanks, Todd! I've integrated Firebase RemoteConfig into our Android app here at Evernote and what I'm seeing so far is 100% line with all your statements. Point 5 would be great for debugging but since things are working, there's no major need for it! :)

Comment: About 3, on Android, even after uninstalling/reinstalling the app, the user is still in the same percentile. It would be useful to have a way for a debug device to "reset" its percentile, to be able to test that the remote config server settings are correct. A related question was opened about that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39977662